# Transferring Windows user profiles from a VMware vSphere VM to a physical PC

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-workstation

Currently we have a VMware vSphere virtual machine and we are thinking of moving away from it and using a physical PC instead. Is there a quick and easy way to transfer the Windows user profiles from the VM to a physical machine?

Comment: Which user profiles are you talking about?

Comment: windows user profiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give no details on exactly what you are trying to do, but I can make the assumption that you are trying to move Windows user profiles from an ESXi VM to a physical Windows box. Is this correct?

If it is, don't let the fact that this is a VM trip you up. The process would be exactly the same moving the profiles from a VM to a physical non-virtualized server as it would from one physical server to another physical server.

Check out the Microsoft [User State Migration Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It is an official MS tool to do exactly what you are needing to do - transfer user profiles from one machine to another.

Comment: ywa that is correct sorry i didnt provide enough details. If i exoain here bit more. We are trying to move off virtual back to physical machines.

Comment: OK, as I said in my answer, the fact that you are moving from virtual to physical doesn't matter. The process of moving the user profiles is *exactly the same* going from virtual to physical as it would be going from **any two servers**.